# How to select TextEdit after Enabled in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I want to design a layout with a PushButton and TextEdit. The TextEdit is disabled at first and only enabled when the PushButton is clicked. When the TextEdit is enabled, it should also be selected.

In other words, what I mean is I can start typing straightway in the TextEdit without click to select it after it is enabled. Like when you open a new tab in your browser, the text cursor will automatically go to the address bar without any clicking.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the QWidget::setFocus() function, [docs here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFocus).